# Connect and disconnect from Bluetooth BLE on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've got a device that is operated by Windows Phone 8.1 and Android phones. Since only one of these phones can use the device at any time, we need to disconnect from the device as soon as we finished the use.

On Android, the library we use is able to connect and disconnect, but on Windows Phone 8.1 I can only seem to connect, I can't find a way to tell the phone to disconnect from the device. I have to manually unpair the phone from the device,

has anyone been able to disconnect a paired Bluetooth device? If yes, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Could edit your question to show the code you're using the connect to the BLE device?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Unfortunately, the Windows BLE API is extremely limited, not nearly as full-featured as Android (or, I presume iOS). I haven't done this on Phone, but the 8.1 WinRT API is the same AFAIK, and all you get is the `GattDevice`. You can close it, but Windows manages the connection itself. All that closing the device does is disconnect your own process from the Windows device, not the actual BLE device.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, Peter... :(

Answer (score 2):

Call Dispose() on the GattDeviceService, ensure that all GattCharacteristic objects are null and DON'T unregister ValueChanged event handlers from GattCharacteristic.
Finally call GC.Collect() (Microsoft told that this is a bug in WP8.1 and should be fixed in Win10)

Comment: On Windows 10 it is working now. Still there is no good solution for WP8.1

Comment: Do you have any reference about that?

Comment: This is not an official solution. It's just what we figured out to get this thing working after hours of debugging.

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9eae39ff-f6ca-4aa9-adaf-97450f2b4a6c/disconnect-bluetooth-low-energy

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating through a [StreamSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx), a Dispose() call will disconnect.

Depending on your code, a [using()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement might be the most elegant way to do so.

Comment: Nope, I'm using GattDevice items :(

Answer (score 0):

This may not help with win8 apps, but for anyone working on UWP apps this article is helpful for pairing and unpairing:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices

The gist of it is you call DeviceInformation.Pairing.UnpairAsync method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationpairing.unpairasync

Calling that method pops up the windows dialog asking the user for permission to unpair the device.